# mc_shipping not showing in IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

Every other field is showing but the mc_shipping.

This is how I call it in IPN:

```
$mc_shipping = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mc_shipping']);
```

Does it work for anybody?

Figured it out. See bellow.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` and check if it exists and has some value

Comment: that doesn't seem to be working in my email error msgs no matter what variable I put in.

Comment: what doesn't seem to be working? Have you checked if **there is something in that variable**?

Comment: yes I'm trying var_dump just not sure how to check it on my ipn. If I send myself a msg it doesn't show any value even if I change the variable in var_dump

Comment: how about $test=print_r($_POST,1); and include $test in the email

Comment: That doesn't work either

Comment: sounds like your doing something quite wrong, how about post your full script/

Comment: good that you solved it,  as we said, check the post values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your supposed to use shipping instead of mc_shipping. Manual is a bit confusing.

Comment: mc_shipping is only returned with particular button types (such as 'Add to Cart').